# Prove the convergence of the sequence using the definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I started learning sequences today and my teacher made an introduction to sequences and convergence of sequences. Not long after the beginning of the class, the teacher wrote and explained the definition of the limit of a sequence:
$(a\in\mathbb{R})$ is the limit of a sequence if:
$$(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n>n_0)|a_n-a|<\epsilon$$

I understand the definition, but, I don't quite understand the proof by the definition that some number is the limit of the sequence.

For example:
Show that $a=0$ is the limit of the sequence:
$$b_n=\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}$$
Here's what the teacher did:

If we go with the definition, then we have:
$$|b_n-0|=\Bigg|\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}\Bigg|=\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}$$
since $n\in\mathbb{N}$

then we have:
$$\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}=\frac{2(n+2)}{n(n+2)+n-1}\leq\frac{2(n+2)}{n(n+2)}=$$
$$=\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon$$
$$n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$$
$$n_0=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}\bigg\rfloor$$
What bothers me is why we couldn't, for example, do this like this:
$$\frac{2n+4}{n^2+3n-1}=\frac{2(n+2)}{2(n+2)+n-1}\leq\frac{2(n+2)}{2(n+2)}$$
which leads us to something indefinite, I guess. (typo)

Or, let's look at this example (we have to prove that $c_n$ converges to $1$):
$c_n=\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}$
$$|c_n-1|=\bigg|\frac{3n^2+1}{3n^2+2n+1}-1\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{-2n}{3n^2+2n+1}\bigg|=\frac{2n}{3n^2+2n+1}=$$
$$=\frac{2n}{2n(\frac{3n}{2}+1)+1}\leq\frac{2n}{2n(\frac{3n}{2}+1)}=\frac{2}{3n+2}<\frac{2}{3n}<\epsilon$$
$$3n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$$
$$n>\frac{2}{3 \epsilon}$$
$$n_0=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{2}{3 \epsilon}}\bigg\rfloor$$

I did the second example, but I still don't understand the proof by definition.

**Edit:** I made some typos which made me not understand this. But, even though everything looks logical now, I'm still a bit confused by these proofs.

Comment: You have some typos in the steps. In the first example, the $2(n+2)$ in the denominator should be $n(n+2)$, then you wouldn't have that question. Your second example looks correct except that the $\epsilon$ should be in the denominator. So where did you not understand?

Comment: @KittyL Could you please post an answer where you try to prove by definition that the sequence $c_n$ converges to 0 and how you would come to a contradiction that it doesn't?

Comment: Maybe you didnt quite understand the definition. If you are given a sequence $cn$ which converges to $a$ then you need to find an $n_o$ so that for every $n>n_o$ $| c_n-a |$<$\epsilon$.

Comment: To prove that a sequence $a_n$ does _not_ converge to a given number $a$ you can find a particular $\epsilon$ such that $|a-a_n|>\epsilon$ for infinitely many values of $n$. For your $c_n$, $|c_n - 0|>\frac13$ for all $n > 0$, which is infinitely many, so $c_n$ does not converge to $0$. Of course, finding that $c_n$ converges to $1$ is also a perfectly good proof that it doesn't converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want an example to show that a sequence does not converge to a number, say, $a$, or to show that a sequence does not converge.

I will use the example $c_n=\cos(\pi n)$. We will show that it does not converge to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

We pick $k=2,4,6,...$. Then the subsequence $|c_k-0|=1>\epsilon$ for any $0<\epsilon<1$. So the limit of $c_n$ is not $0$.

To show that it has no limit, we pick two subsequences, $k=2, 4, 6, ...$, $m=1, 3, 5, ...$. We see that the two subsequences $c_k$ and $c_m$ converge to $1$ and $-1$, respectively. So $c_n$ has no limit.